# Portlets getting called Automatically

Tags: spring-mvc, portlet, websphere-portal, spring-portlet-mvc

We stucked in a strange problem. We are developing IBM Spring Portlet MVC application WPS 8.5. We have 3 evnironments DEV, UAT and PROD. UAT and PROD are clustered and DEV is non clustered. Now thing is all my portlts in the application are getting called automatically on UAT and PROD even no one is using the application but this is not happening on DEV environment.

Someone please guide me how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by increasing the Schedular time of Search crawling from 1 minute to 1 day.